# make elements change color with button hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I seem to be struggling with this.
Im want to make other elements change with button hover.
what im trying to do is , when you hover on the "continue reading" button on the homepage , then for the title and post meta to change color.

The site url is:

http://staging.conversationlab.com/lions_valley/

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: cool thanks for the info, i will put in more info next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method on the more links to trigger a function that applies or removes styling to their [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) like...

```
$(".more-link").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("your-class-with-styling");
    $(this).siblings(".post-meta").addClass("your-class-with-styling");
    $(this).siblings("h2").addClass("your-class-with-styling");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("your-class-with-styling");
    $(this).siblings(".post-meta").removeClass("your-class-with-styling");
    $(this).siblings("h2").removeClass("your-class-with-styling");    
  }
);
```

I would probably add a class to the h2 to target, though, to make sure that it wouldn't conflict with any other h2s that MAY end up in those article sections at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add some css:

```
<style>
#buttonid:hover {
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
</style>
```

where the #buttonid is declared on your button:

```
<button id="buttonid"> my button</button>
```

more info = better answer/s

Answer (score 0):

You can see here how to do it. https://jsfiddle.net/5aybmjk7/

Basically I just added an ID / additional class to your code and then attached the relevant jquery that used mouseover and mouseout to highlight/unhighlight the title by adding or removing a class with CSS attached to it.

```
$('#here').mouseover(function () {
    $(".highlightMe").addClass('colored');
});

$('#here').mouseout(function () {
    $(".highlightMe").removeClass('colored');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.et_pb_posts article').find('.more-link').on('hover', function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.post-meta a').addClass('YOUR_CLASS')
});
```

Try that